# Property 'value' does not exist for $event.target.value in typescript/angularjs

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get input from a textbox and dynamically add it to a card on the bottom of the page, like so:

```
<div>
<h2 class="projectTitle">Project 1 - The Dynamic Business Card</h2>
<hr />
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Modify Your Business Card</legend>
        <label>First Name</label><input class="firstNameInput" (input)="firstName=$event.target.value" /><br /> 
        <!-- <label>First Name</label><input [(ngModel)]="firstName" /><br /> -->
        <label>Last Name</label><input class="lastNameInput" (input)="lastName=$event.target.value" /><br />
        <!-- <label>Last Name</label><input [(ngModel)]="lastName" /><br /> --> 
        <label>Phone Number</label><input class="phoneNumberInput" (input)="phoneNumber=$event.target.value" />
        <!-- <label>Phone Name</label><input [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber" /><br /> --> 
    </fieldset>
</form>

<button class="card">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="left big">{{phoneNumber}}</div>
        <div class="right"><p><span class="big">E</span>rnst & <span class="big">S</span>ohn</p><p><span class="med no-space">A W</span><span class="small no-space">iley </span><span class="med no-space">B</span><span class="small no-space">rand</span></p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="capitalize">{{firstName}} <span class="capitalize">{{lastName}}</span></p>
        <p class="capitalize">Vice <span class="capitalize">P</span>resident</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p><span class="med">375 E</span><span class="small">xchange </span><span class="med">P</span><span class="small">lace </span><span class="med">N</span><span class="small">ew </span><span class="med">Y</span><span class="small">ork</span><span class="med">, N. Y. 10099 F</span><span class="small">ax </span><span class="med">201 555 6390 T</span><span class="small">elex </span><span class="med">10 4534</span>
    </p>
    </div>
</button>
</div>
```

My component is defined as:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-projects-home',
 templateUrl: './projects-home.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./projects-home.component.css']
})
export class ProjectsHomeComponent implements OnInit {

  firstName: string ="William";//default values
  lastName: string = "Wallace";
  phoneNumber: string = "(201) 748-6000";




  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  }
```

The issue I am having is that at $event.target.value I am getting a compiling error saying value is not a correct property. I am just learning angular and this set of code comes directly from course material therefore I am stumped to why this is a giving a compiling error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple ways of handling this. The way you're trying to do isn't working (I think) because typescript can't infer the type of $event.target.

**Binding with $event.target**

You need a function to cast the element type so typescript knows how to treat it. Using [this page](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding-concepts) as a guide, I was able to pass $event.target and update the firstName element. The same can be done to the other elements, but I wanted to show how `ngModel` can accomplish the same thing.

```
<input name="firstName" (input)="firstName=getValue($event)" [value]="firstName" class="firstNameInput" />
```

Note the dynamic `[value]` - this tells angular that whatever is typed into the input element will be assigned to the `firstName` variable. Then in the component, the event.target is `typed` and the value is passed back.

```
getValue(event: Event): string {
  return (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
}
```

**Binding with ngModel**

To bind with ngModel, you need to give an identifier to the form tag (I used #theForm)

```
<form #theForm>
```

... then use 2 way binding on each element, like:

```
<input name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="firstName"  class="firstNameInput" />
```

*Note:* The form tag id, name property and ngModel with 2 way binding (signified by encasing in both `[(ngModel)]` are required.

Working version here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nxjd65?file=src/app/app.component.ts